# Spring security logout does not clear authenticated user

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using the default logout mechanism of Spring security to logout the user. From my front end app which is a React app, I call GET on '/logout' of the backend service. However, I see that the authentication details are not cleared after logout and same user is reported as logged in from previous login. But the authentication is cleared when the same '/logout' URL is called from Postman. Here's my security config:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("*"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PUT","OPTIONS","PATCH", "DELETE"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));

        http
                .cors()
                .configurationSource(request -> corsConfiguration)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/notes/**")
                .authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/register")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .permitAll()
                        .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> {
                                    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
                                }
                        )
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                )

                .httpBasic();
    }
```

Here're the response headers for /logout:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 07 Feb 2022 12:42:16 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Here're the request headers for /logout:

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,te;q=0.8
authorization: Basic dGVzdHVzZXIxOnBhc3Mx
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36
```

Can someone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: are you doing a post from postman, cause when you are logging out, you are making a state change to the server, you should be doing a post request, not a get

Comment: Are you sure that the frontend request is working? If so, debugging the `LogoutFilter` would be the way to find the problem here

Comment: How do you log in with Postman? Why are you configure `.httpBasic();`? Do you really use login form with React? Show your request and response with headers (for example a screenshot of your dev tool in your browser, F12).

Comment: I want to use Basic authentication in my backend service, so I used `httpBasic()`